# How to avoid multi-user overwriting on Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet making some calculations and multiple users will use this calculator.

Eventually, they will be updating the same field to get a result and I couldn't find a safe way to avoid overwriting.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, all changes the users make are saved automatically and right away, and users see each other's changes in real time. There are a couple of ways to avoid overlapping edits:

1. Create a separate copy of the Google Sheet for every user. The easiest way to do this is to give them a link to the  spreadsheet that ends in `/copy` instead of the usual `/edit`.
2. Redesign the spreadsheet so that all entry cells and the result cell are in the same row. Instruct the users to enter their input each in a row of their own. Use an array formula to automatically calculate the result for every row that gets inserted.
3. Rewrite the calculator user interface as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). This requires the use of HTML and JavaScript in the UI, but the calculations can still be done with array formulas in a Google Sheet. See the [Web App Demo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153204/embed-an-interactive-calculator-in-my-website-using-google-sheets) answer for more information and sample code.